# 3d max vray proxy objects. Can I get back to the editable poly?

Tags: 3ds-max

I converted objects to vray mesh. Now I need to edit it as an editable poly. Is there any way to do that?

I tried to convert it to an editable poly, but vray mesh preview polygons only converting back to editable poly.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Hello and welcome 3D is a bad fit for this site. It would be fine to ask 3d questions if you were asking about design. But you are not, your asking about how to use 3d apps which is not on scope, not here and not really on superuser either. There really is no home for this kinds of questions on entire stackexhange. Such a place has been [proposed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics?referrer=QKFO2qIfMkCKQcyqcR7pKw2), however it is still in need of users. More people, about 130 currently, need commit for it to go beta.

Answer (score 2):

In the object's Modify panel, make sure the option of "show whole mesh" is selected before you convert the object to an editable poly.

[image]